# Database Updating but get warning saying Not Updated

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I am developing an application in PHP and everything is going well-ish so far. However, I am getting an error when updating a database table using PHP and MySQLi. The table updates just fine but I get a "Cannot Update" message.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){//if the submit button is clicked

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['lname']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['phone']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);

    $sql="UPDATE admin_users SET name='$name', lname='$lname', phone='$phone', email='$email'";

    $mysqli->query($sql) or die("Cannot update");//update or error
}
```

Can anyone see any issues in this that can make it do the right thing?

Comment: you need to know what the real error is; you're not doing that

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to do this? I have tried $mysqli->query($sql) or die  . mysqli_error($mysqli);//update or error

Comment: Found the error: Duplicate entry 'dan@cvia.org.au' for key 'email' - But there is only one entry.

Comment: it's because you don't have a `WHERE` clause and is trying to update your entire database.

Comment: Fixed. The row email was a unique entry so it was trying to duplicate it rather than update it. Removing the Unique key resolved it. Fred, if I try to add a WHERE clause, it comes up with Undefined Variable.

Comment: the `WHERE` clause will depend on which row you want it set to. I.e.: `WHERE id=1` if you have one, which you should and set it to auto increment.

Comment: Hi. Yeah I have a id and when I set it to WHERE id='$id' I get Undefined Variable id

Comment: All fixed. I just changed it to id='1' as you have and it is all working fine now. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I posted an answer instead, seeing the one below and being wrong.

Comment: where the question should be marked as solved, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comments, you are trying to update your entire database without using a `WHERE` clause.

That's why you received that error:

> Found the error: Duplicate entry 'email@example.com' for key 'email'

which I replaced using a generic email address.

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Using an `id` as an additional column and being an auto_increment would be better and making sure you are not trying to update the same column with a constraint on it.

The `or die("Cannot update")` did not help you here to get the real error, `mysqli_error($mysqli)` will.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php